# speeding up initial display of contextMenu?

Tags: qt

**Environment**: Qt 5.1 OSX 10.7.5

I am showing a contextMenu when a `Qt::RightButton` event is received.

**Issue:** It works fine except that the initial display is very slow and can take 3-5 seconds to display the menu. Any subsequent displays are immediate. The delay is long enough so that the user can think nothing is happening.

**Question:** Is there any way to preload or otherwise speed up the initial display of the contextMenu?

I've tried initializing it in my class constructor:

```
   contextMenu = new QMenu(this);
   QAction *saveAction=contextMenu->addAction("Save");
   connect(saveAction,SIGNAL(triggered()),this,SLOT(saveSlot()));
```

I've tried declaring it as a pointer and as a... (not pointer? ;-)

```
  QMenu *contextMenu;
```

---

This is the `mousePressEvent` that executes to show the contextMenu.

```
void RPImageLabel::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    if (!imageRect.contains(event->pos())) return;

    origin = event->pos();

    this->setFocus();

    if (event->button()==Qt::RightButton){
        if (selectionRect.contains(origin))
            //            contextMenu.exec(this->mapToGlobal(origin));
            contextMenu->exec(this->mapToGlobal(origin));

    } else {
        selectionStarted=true;
        selectionRect.setTopLeft(origin);
        selectionRect.setBottomRight(origin);

        if (rubberBand->isHidden()){
            rubberBand->setGeometry(QRect(origin, origin));
            rubberBand->show();
            repaint();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the time spent? Is it somewhere inside Qt or is it in your code?

Comment: @rubenvb - I just updated my question with the full `mousePressEvent` method. Doesn't seem like anything there except perhaps 'setFocus' that would slow things down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I solved this by changing the `contextMenuPolicy` from `DefaultContextMenu` to `ActionsContextMenu` for the widget in Qt Creator.

I'm new to Qt so just guessing here but perhaps this uses a Qt contextMenu instead of the OSX menu? In any event, it displays immediately now. However it does throw an alert on certain conditions:

```
QNSView mouseDragged: 
Internal mouse button tracking invalid (missing Qt::LeftButton)
```

Not clear what is going on but I see that there has been [a bug report filed](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-31937?attachmentOrder=desc) which may be related.

---

[image]